# ng2-smart-table row index

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using ng2-smart-table in my angular project, its working as expected. I  just want to know how can I show row number in each row. From documentation and examples on google, all I can think of is setting a property in the data itslef , which is not a good idea. If there is any way or work around please suggest. here is my data settings and sampel data to my ng2-smart-table

```
settings2 = {
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID',
        filter: true,
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Fact',
        filter: true,
      },
      description: {
        title: 'Description',
        filter: true,
      },
    },
    actions: {
      add: false,
      edit: false,
      delete: false,
      custom: [
        {
          name: 'view',
          title: `<i class="ti-eye text-success m-r-10" data-target="#view"></i>`,
        },
        {
          name: 'edit',
          title: `<i class="ti-pencil text-info m-r-10" data-target="#update"></i>`,
        },
        {
          name: 'delete',
          title: `<i class="ti-trash text-danger m-r-10"></i>`
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Data -

```
[{
"id":  "770e6370-cf14-4a0a-b9db-0a6e99b5783b" ,
"list": [
{
"description":  "Coopentity" ,
"type":  "CO_OP"
} ,
{
"description":  "" ,
"type":  "FARM"
} ,
{
"description":  "" ,
"type":  "FACTORY"
} ,
{
"description":  "" ,
"type":  "AUDITING_FIRM"
}
] ,
"name":  "entity_types"
}]
```

HTML -

```
 <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings2" [source]="facts" (custom)="onCustom($event)" class=""></ng2-smart-table>
```

Comment: Is issue open now ?

Answer (score 1):

**In settings of smart table**

```
index:{
  title: 'sr_no',
  type: 'text',
  valuePrepareFunction: (value,row,cell) => {
    return cell.row.index;
   }
}
```

Comment: And what next? How to take this value within the component code?

Answer (score 0):

If assume your dataSource in component.ts body is:

```
source: LocalDataSource;
```

in your columns definitions:

```
valuePrepareFunction : (val,row,cell)=>{
   const pager = this.source.getPaging();
   const ret = (pager.page-1) * pager.perPage + cell.row.index+1;

   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you want to get the index in the typescript maybe this could help you:

In html

```
<ng2-smart-table #table [settings]="settings" [source]="source"></ng2-smart-table>
```

In typescript

```
@ViewChild('table', { static: false }) table;
getIndex(columnName: string) {
let index = 0;
  for (const column in this.table.columns) {
    if (column === columName) {
      console.log(index);
    }
  index++;
  }
}
```

Hope if this is what you were searching.